# bash group similar line in html table followed by empty line

Tags: html, bash, shell, awk

I am trying to group similar line followed by newline in a HTML table using bash/awk but I am not able to get desired output. This is what I tried till now.

EDIT1: Added input file as requested. It could be any password file. This is not the actual task but the task that I am doing is mostly similar.
EDIT2: Given expected output in text format

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

{
echo "Username,UserID,GroupID,Home Directory,Shell"
while IFS=":" read -r userName encPass userId groupId userComment homeDir userShell; do
        echo "${userName}, ${userId}, ${groupId}, ${homeDir}, ${userShell}"
done < <(sort -t: -k7 /etc/passwd)
} | \

awk -F',' 'BEGIN {
    split("80,80,150,150,", widths, ",")
    print "<style>\
        .my_table {font-size:8.0pt; font-family:\"Verdana\",\"sans-serif\"; border-bottom:3px double black; border-collapse: collapse; }\n\
        .my_table tr.header{border-bottom:3px double black; center; border: 1px solid black; }\n\
        .my_table td {text-align: center; border: 1px solid black; word-break: break-all; padding: 8px 8px; white-space: nowrap; }\n\
        .my_table th {text-align: center; solid-black; border: 1px solid black; word-wrap: break-word; color: blue; white-space: nowrap; }\
    </style>"
    print "<table class=\"my_table\">"
}
NR == 1{
    print "<tr class=\"header\">"
    tag = "th"
}
NR != 1{
    print "<tr>"
    tag = "td"
}
{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) print "<" tag " width=\"" widths[i] "\">" $i "</" tag ">"
    print "</tr>"
}
END { print "</table>"}' >> passwd.html
```

## Input File

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin
daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin
adm:x:3:4:adm:/var/adm:/sbin/nologin
lp:x:4:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/sbin/nologin
sync:x:5:0:sync:/sbin:/bin/sync
shutdown:x:6:0:shutdown:/sbin:/sbin/shutdown
halt:x:7:0:halt:/sbin:/sbin/halt
mail:x:8:12:mail:/var/spool/mail:/sbin/nologin
operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin
games:x:12:100:games:/usr/games:/sbin/nologin
ftp:x:14:50:FTP User:/var/ftp:/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:99:99:Nobody:/:/sbin/nologin
dbus:x:81:81:System message bus:/:/sbin/nologin
rpc:x:32:32:Rpcbind Daemon:/var/lib/rpcbind:/sbin/nologin
sshd:x:74:74:Privilege-separated SSH:/var/empty/sshd:/sbin/nologin
chrony:x:997:995::/var/lib/chrony:/sbin/nologin
tss:x:59:59:Account used by the trousers package to sandbox the tcsd daemon:/dev/null:/sbin/nologin
nginx:x:995:991:Nginx web server:/var/lib/nginx:/sbin/nologin
user1:x:1002:1003::/home/user1:/bin/bash
user2:x:1002:1003::/home/user2:/bin/bash
saslauth:x:993:76:Saslauthd user:/run/saslauthd:/sbin/nologin
mailnull:x:47:47::/var/spool/mqueue:/sbin/nologin
smmsp:x:51:51::/var/spool/mqueue:/sbin/nologin
```

## Expected Output in text format

Values are separated by actual tabs. This is the output when piping through `column -ts $'\t'`

```
Username         UserID  GroupID  Home Directory   Shell           Count
root             0       0        /root            /bin/bash       3
user1            1001    1001     /home/user1      /bin/bash
user2            1003    1004     /home/user2      /bin/bash
sync             5       0        /sbin            /bin/sync       1
halt             7       0        /sbin            /sbin/halt      1
adm              3       4        /var/adm         /sbin/nologin   8
bin              1       1        /bin             /sbin/nologin
chrony           997     995      /var/lib/chrony  /sbin/nologin
operator         11      0        /root            /sbin/nologin
sshd             74      74       /var/empty/sshd  /sbin/nologin
systemd-network  192     192      /                /sbin/nologin
tcpdump          72      72       /                /sbin/nologin
tss              59      59       /dev/null        /sbin/nologin
shutdown         6       0        /sbin            /sbin/shutdown  1
```

## Current Output

[image]

## Desired Output

[image]

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts in form of code in your question. Could you please do add sample input also so that we could better understand this question. Kindly do add the same and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I added sample input as well text of expected output

Comment: why no `lp` user on the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go the XHTML route, meaning that once your data can be read by an XML parser, you'll have *very* powerful tools at hand to manipulate your data.
Your html result is, short of the wrapping tag, XHTML already, so let me suggest a solution that uses *xmlstarlet* to transform your list:

If you (as a final step) pipe your HTML result through the following bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

xargs -0 -I{} echo "<xhtml>{}</xhtml>" \
| xmlstarlet sel --indent -t \
  --elem xhtml \
  --copy-of //style \
  --match //table --elem table --copy-of @* \
  --match //tr[child::th] --elem tr --copy-of th --elem th -v "'Count'" --break \
  --match //tr[child::td] --elem tr --copy-of td --if "not(preceding-sibling::tr[td[5]=current()/td[5]])" \
    --var "cnt=count(following-sibling::tr[td[5]=current()/td[5]]) +1" --elem td --attr rowspan --value-of '$cnt' --break --value-of '$cnt'
```

... then you'll have your list formatted in your desired HTML output format (short of the separating rows after each group - I will leave it as a playground for you to further improve the result to your liking).

Comment: Awesome. It worked like charm. It doesn't give new line as shown in my expected output but that is fine. I will figure out something else.

Comment: I didn't know xmlstarlet is so much powerful

Answer (score 2):

Will this work for you?

I'm using perl instead of awk. Perl comes with every linux distro.

```
#! /bin/bash

cat <<"HTMLEND"
<style>
    .my_table {font-size:8.0pt; font-family:"Verdana","sans-serif"; border-bottom:3px double black; border-collapse: collapse;}
    .my_table tr.header{border-bottom:3px double black; center; border: 1px solid black;}
    .my_table td {text-align: center; border: 1px solid black; word-break: break-all; padding: 8px 8px; white-space: nowrap;}
    .my_table th {text-align: center; solid-black; border: 1px solid black; word-wrap: break-word; color: blue; white-space: nowrap;}
</style>
<table class="my_table">
<tr class="header">
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>UserId</th>
    <th>GroupID</th>
    <th>Home Directory</th>
    <th>Shell</th>
    <th>Count</th>
</tr>
HTMLEND

cat pass.txt | perl -e '
    my %data = ();
    while (<>) {
        chomp;
        my @cols = split /:/;
        my $shell = $cols[6];
        $data{$shell}{data} //= [];
        push @{$data{$shell}{data}}, \@cols;
        $data{$shell}{shell} = $shell;
        $data{$shell}{count}++;
    }

    foreach my $shell ( sort keys %data ) {
        my $data = $data{$shell}{data};
        my $count = $data{$shell}{count};
        my $first = 1;
        foreach my $col ( @{$data} ) {
            print "<tr>\n";
            printf "    <td>%s</td>\n", $col->[0];
            printf "    <td>%s</td>\n", $col->[2];
            printf "    <td>%s</td>\n", $col->[3];
            printf "    <td>%s</td>\n", $col->[5];
            printf "    <td>%s</td>\n", $col->[6];
            if ($first) {
                printf "    <td rowspan=\"%s\">%s</td>\n", $count, $count;
            }
            print "</tr>\n";
            $first = 0;
        }
    }
'
echo '</table>'
```

Comment: I don't have any issue with perl as like you said it is available on every linux distribution. I tried your approach but it is calculating the count of all the line in password file instead of particular group that you can see in my expected output. I am not able to figure out the logic that should be applied to get count of each group

Comment: The script should be counting and grouping by `shell` column. Was it supposed to work in a different way? Why the user `lp` is not showing on your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly and that your don't want to touch and previous code your wrote then just create a new column with counts and paste it to the table.

```
awk '{if(NR > 1){print $NF} }' your_current_output_file >yourlastcolumn
uniq -c yourlastcolumn | awk '{ print $2, $1 }' >counts
cat <(echo "Count") <(join yourlastcolumn counts) >newcolumn
paste your_current_output_file newcolumn >newoutput
```